# C++'s double colon used after a class name instead of a namespace

Tags: c++, syntax

I am trying to understand a c++ program listed [here](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITKExamples/blob/master/src/Core/Transform/ApplyAffineTransformFromHomogeneousMatrixAndResample/Code.cxx). I am  confused about the second use of double colons on lines 86-87:

```
 using TransformType = itk::AffineTransform< ScalarType, Dimension >;
 TransformType::Pointer transform = TransformType::New();
```

It looks like `TransformType` is a user-defined type. How would one use it  before `New()`? I heard that the double-colon is to be used following a namespace, but here,  TransformType is a type (namely class) rather than a namespace. Can someone clarify --- should double colon be always used after a namespace in C++? Would it possible to use a dot (like in Java) instead?

Comment: If a class `TransformType` has a static member function `New()`, you can call it using `TransformType::New()`. `::` is the scope resolution operator, it is not limited to namespaces. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup

Comment: The operator `::` is the *scoping* operator, it's used to denote scope. So `TransformType::New()` means (basically) "call the function `New` in the scope of `TransformType`".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you. In that case, would it be possible to use "TransformType.New()" like in Java? I mean, use dot instead of the two columns?

Comment: A class and a namespace each specifies a scope with the same name as themselves.    So `A::B` works if `A` is a struct or a class, or if `A` is a namespace - assuming there is something within the class/namespace named `B`

Comment: No, because `TransformType` is a *type-name*. You can't use it as an object instance (because it isn't).

Comment: Java and C++ use different syntax and semantics.  They are similar appearing languages, but are very different.  They are both good, successful languages, with slightly different charters and different principles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use the scope resolution operator (`::`) to name something in a namespace, or in a class, or in a scoped enum; this is called [qualified lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup).

```
#include <iostream>

namespace N
{
   int x = 0;
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << N::x << '\n';
}
```

Using it with a class usually means you're referring to some `static` member, because otherwise you'd generally be using `objectInstance.member` instead.

```
#include <iostream>

class C
{
public:
   static int x;
}

int C::x = 0;

int main()
{
   std::cout << C::x << '\n';
}
```

Though, within a non-static member function, there are still uses for `::`, such as disambiguating between names that exist concurrently in different bases.

```
class Base
{
public:
   void foo() {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
   void foo()
   {
      // Do base version (omitting Base:: will just call this one again!)
      Base::foo();

      // Now maybe do other things too
   }
};

int main()
{
   Derived obj;
   obj.foo();
}
```

… or for naming a non-`static` member in a scenario where an object context is not required:

```
#include <iostream>

class C
{
public:
   int x;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(C::x) << '\n';

    decltype(C::x) y = 42;
}
```

It's needed with scoped enums because, well, they're scoped; that's the whole point of them. They don't leak into the surrounding scope but have their own which as a result you need to specify specifically.

```
enum class E
{
   Alpha,
   Bravo,
   Charlie
};

void foo(E value) {}

int main()
{
   foo(E::Alpha);
}
```

Some languages let you access `static` members of classes with the type name followed by `.`, just like you'd access non-`static` members of classes with the object name followed by `.`. C++ is not one of those languages.

By the way, this is legal:

```
#include <iostream>

class C
{
public:
   int x = 42;
};

int main()
{
   C obj;
   std::cout << obj.C::x << '\n';
//                  ^^^ what?!
}
```

Adding scope resolution to `x` here is not necessary, because the language already knows from the `obj.` that you're asking for a member of a class `C`. But you can still add it if you want. It's just usually "done for you" in this case.

Comment: Since you mentioned `obj.C::x`, you might also want to mention `sizeof(C::x)` or `decltype(C::x)` for a non-static `x`.